# not able to print user's input in PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I am not able to  print the user's input from `GUI.py` code.  When I try to print, prints something like this[`PyQt4.QtGui.QTextEdit object at 0x0000000002BE8288`]:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, 
    _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def merger(self):
        location = self.plainTextEdit_location
        print "%s" % (location)

        date = self.textEdit1_date
        print "%s" % (date)

        session = self.textEdit3_session
        print "%s" % (session)

        dept1_rangefrom = self.plainTextEdit1_from1
        print "%d" %(dept1_rangefrom)

        dept2_rangefrom = self.plainTextEdit2_from2
        print "%d" % (dept2_rangefrom)

        dept1_rangeto = self.plainTextEdit4_to
        print "%d" % (dept1_rangeto)

        dept2_rangeto = self.plainTextEdit3_to1
        print "%d" % (dept2_rangeto)

        #self.textEdit2_month.setText(test)
        #print " "+str(month.text())


    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(637, 361)
        self.comboBox_dept2 = QtGui.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox_dept2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 80, 69, 22))
        self.comboBox_dept2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_dept2"))
        self.comboBox_dept2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_dept2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_dept2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_dept2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_dept2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_dept2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1 = QtGui.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 80, 69, 22))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_2_dept1"))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 101, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 101, 31))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.textEdit1_date = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit1_date.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 30, 91, 31))
        self.textEdit1_date.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit1_date"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 101, 31))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.textEdit3_session = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit3_session.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 130, 51, 31))
        self.textEdit3_session.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit3_session"))
        self.plainTextEdit1_from1 = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.plainTextEdit1_from1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 190, 71, 
        31))

        self.plainTextEdit1_from1.setObjectName
        (_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit1_from1"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 250, 111, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 21, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        self.plainTextEdit4_to = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.plainTextEdit4_to.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 71, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit4_to.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit4_to"))
        self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 250, 21, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
        self.label_7 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 111, 21))
        self.label_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_7"))
        self.plainTextEdit3_to1 = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.plainTextEdit3_to1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 190, 71, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit3_to1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8
        ("plainTextEdit3_to1"))
        self.plainTextEdit2_from2 = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.plainTextEdit2_from2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 250, 71, 
        31))
        self.plainTextEdit2_from2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8
        ("plainTextEdit2_from2"))
        self.label_8 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 30, 111, 31))
        self.label_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_8"))
        self.textEdit2_month = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit2_month.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 30, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit2_month.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit2_month"))
        self.label_9 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 320, 101, 21))
        self.label_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_9"))
        self.plainTextEdit_location = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.plainTextEdit_location.setGeometry
        (QtCore.QRect(130, 310, 311, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_location.setObjectName(_fromUtf8
        ("plainTextEdit_location"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 120, 151, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.merger)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.comboBox_dept2.setItemText(0, _translate
        ("Dialog", "EEE", None))
        self.comboBox_dept2.setItemText(1, _translate
        ("Dialog", "CSE", None))
        self.comboBox_dept2.setItemText(2, _translate
        ("Dialog", "ECE", None))
        self.comboBox_dept2.setItemText(3, _translate
        ("Dialog", "IT", None))
        self.comboBox_dept2.setItemText(4, _translate
        ("Dialog", "MECH", None))
        self.comboBox_dept2.setItemText(5, _translate
        ("Dialog", "CIVIL", None))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setItemText(0, _translate
        ("Dialog", "CSE", None))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setItemText(1, _translate
        ("Dialog", "ECE", None))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setItemText(2, _translate
        ("Dialog", "IT", None))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setItemText(3, _translate
        ("Dialog", "EEE", None))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setItemText(4, _translate
        ("Dialog", "MECH", None))
        self.comboBox_2_dept1.setItemText(5, _translate
        ("Dialog", "CIVIL", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "SELECT DEPT", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "DATE", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "SESSION", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", 
        "RANGE OF 2ND DEPT", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TO", None))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TO", None))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", 
        "RANGE OF 1ST DEPT", None))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "MONTH", None))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "LOCATION", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "SCHEDULE", None))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use pyqt4 so I have had to rely on the manual.
Using the QTextEdit widget, you access value using toPlainText().

```
def merger(self):
    location = self.plainTextEdit_location.toPlainText()
    print "%s" % (location)

    date = self.textEdit1_date.toPlainText()
    print "%s" % (date)

    session = self.textEdit3_session.toPlainText()
    print "%s" % (session)

    dept1_rangefrom = self.plainTextEdit1_from1.toPlainText()
    print "%s" %(dept1_rangefrom)

    dept2_rangefrom = self.plainTextEdit2_from2.toPlainText()
    print "%s" % (dept2_rangefrom)

    dept1_rangeto = self.plainTextEdit4_to.toPlainText()
    print "%s" % (dept1_rangeto)

    dept2_rangeto = self.plainTextEdit3_to1.toPlainText()
    print "%s" % (dept2_rangeto)

    #self.textEdit2_month.setText(test)
    #print " "+str(month.text())
```